# How can I reuse methods in TestNG?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, methods, testng

I am an intern automating testing of a large corporation's website and honestly, I'm in over my head. I'm trying to learn everything and use it at the same time and no one else in this firm knows how to use the tools I'm using, so I don't have many options as far as asking people for help. So this may be fairly obvious. Anyway, I'm using TestNG with Selenium in Eclipse, using Java. I wrote a pretty significant number of tests before I found TestNG, so now I'm trying to rewrite them all with TestNG because it gives much better feedback and doesn't fail the whole test because of one test. The problem is, my tests have a lot of methods that I reuse many, many times. One of my tests is about 140 lines of code and if I wrote it with my current knowledge of TestNG, it'd be 1000's of lines of code. So my question is, is there a way to call the same method repeatedly and throughout a test with TestNG or am I condemned to copy and pasting for hours?

TL;DR - How can I reuse code with TestNG? Can you point me toward some examples of effective and efficient structure using TestNG?

Here is some of my current code without TestNG:

```
public static void sideBarNavAll(WebDriver driver, String site){
    driver.get(site);
    List<WebElement> topNavLinks = driver.findElement(By.className("topNavigationMenu")).findElements(By.className("menuLink"));
    int numLinks = topNavLinks.size();
    String[] topNavTitlesAndLinks = new String[numLinks*2];
    topNavTitlesAndLinks = createArray(topNavLinks);
    System.out.println("Filled titles and links array.");
    for (int x=1; x<topNavTitlesAndLinks.length; x+=2){
        driver.get(topNavTitlesAndLinks[x]);
        openDropDowns(driver);
        try{
            List<WebElement> menu = driver.findElement(By.className("asideNavigationMenu")).findElements(By.className("itemLink"));
            String[] menuArray = new String[menu.size()*2];
            menuArray = createArray(menu);
            checkValidity(menuArray, driver);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            if (topNavTitlesAndLinks[x-1].contains("Endodontics")){
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Endodontics"));
                Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                action.moveToElement(element).perform();
                WebElement subElement = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Access"));
                action.moveToElement(subElement);
                action.click();
                action.perform();
                openDropDowns(driver);
                List<WebElement> menu = driver.findElement(By.className("asideNavigationMenu")).findElements(By.className("itemLink"));
                String[] menuArray = new String[menu.size()*2];
                menuArray = createArray(menu);
                checkValidity(menuArray, driver);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void checkValidity(String[] array, WebDriver driver){
    String partialURL = "";
    int brokenLinks = 0;
    for (int x=1; x<array.length; x+=2){
        partialURL = anonUserSitemapExperience.getPartialURL(driver, array[x]);
        if (partialURL.isEmpty()){
            System.err.println("The link \""+array[x]+"\" intended for the "+array[x-1]+" page is either broken or an external site.");
            brokenLinks++;
            brokenLinksTot++;
        }
        else{
            int found = anonUserSitemapExperience.findMatch(array, array.length, partialURL);
            if (found<1){
                System.err.println("A match was not found for "+array[x-1]+".\n"+array[x]+"\n"+partialURL);
                brokenLinks++;
                brokenLinksTot++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.err.println("\n"+brokenLinks+" broken link(s) was/were found.\n");
}

public static void openDropDowns(WebDriver driver){
    List<WebElement> dropdownArrows = driver.findElements(By.className("dropdownToggler"));
    Iterator<WebElement> itr = dropdownArrows.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        try{
            itr.next().click();
        }
        catch(ElementNotVisibleException e){
        }
    }
}

public static String[] createArray(List<WebElement> list){
    String[] linkArray = new String[list.size()*2];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int x=1; x<linkArray.length; x+=2){
        linkArray[x] = list.get(counter).getAttribute("href");
        try{
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C2%AE", "®");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%20", " ");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%27", "'");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%A4", "ä");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%B6", "ö");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%BC", "ü");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%84", "Ä");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%96", "Ö");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%9C", "Ü");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%E2%80%93", "–");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%E2%84%A2", "™");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%25", "%");
            counter++;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
    int counter2 = 0;
    for (int x=0; x<linkArray.length; x+=2){
        linkArray[x] = list.get(counter2).getText();
        counter2++;
    }
    return linkArray;
}
```

}

The method `openDropDowns` is called multiple times and the `checkValidity` method has a huge `for loop` in it (over 1300 iterations total). I would like to be able to write what the `for loop` does into a method, then call it over and over so that I can get a pass/fail from TestNG. Hopefully this clarifies what I'm asking for. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get the question. A TestNG test suite is "just a Java class" and so you can just create private methods and call them in your public test methods. You can make them protected and stick them in a shared base class too.

Comment: @Gimby With TestNG, the flow of the program is determined by annotations and priority above each method, not by calls made within other methods. I can call other methods, but then they aren't treated separately as far as I know and I need separate pass/fail feedback on each method.

Comment: Perhaps try posting an example of code you want to 're-use' but cannot currently.

Comment: @Gimby I added some code, pointed out what I was talking about and hopefully clarified my question a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

@burnst14, here is an example of a test case i have, this is an End-to-End scenario, it covers sequentially executing 5 REST API calls.  Don't worry about what exactly it is doing, just know that I am creating methods, and reusing them in multiple tests.  I am sure some will disagree with the way i have done a few things below, but know that each method below, is being reused multiple times.  In fact, the structure is pretty much repeated, the "RunProvision()" is what often gets replaced.

```
@DataProvider(name = "data1")
public Object[][] data1() throws Exception{
    Object[][] retObj = Utils.getExcelData(DATAFILE, sheet, "xxx", "yyy");
    return retObj;
}


@Test(priority=1, dataProvider="data1", groups={"group1"})
public void TestCase1(Integer id, Map<String,String> hmData, ITestContext ctx) throws Exception {
    try {
        Utils.logTitle(1);
        setAttribute(hmData, ctx);
        populateMaps(hmData);
        runProvision();
        buildSummaryPassed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        buildReporterSummary(e.getMessage());
        buildSummaryFailed(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put it in context of your program so I can see the actual calls to the method? That's the part I can't figure out.

Comment: All i have in my @Test are methods, which is just java code.  I think you need to start a new thread, post some code that you have confusion about, and let us work through it.  otherwise, i'm not entirely clear what exactly you're trying to solve that you can't figuer out above.

Comment: I have done so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322077/certain-tests-not-reporting-in-testng). Thank you for all your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the Page Object Model. Using this model its easy to maintain and reuse your classes and methods as much as possible.

The basic concept is that you create a page object for each page you want to test . This page object encapsulates all information and methods for the page and if the page changes in anyway you'll only have to update the code here. This in turn allows your TestNG tests to focus solely on the actual testing. Theres loads of information about the page object model available online, [here](http://blog.activelylazy.co.uk/2011/07/09/page-objects-in-selenium-2-0/) is one i had bookmarked.

Comment: This is a good idea, but not exactly what I meant. I'm looking for a way to reuse implementation. For instance, I have a sitemap page I need to crawl and that requires verifying that every link goes where it's supposed to. Right now, I'm using for loops, but I want to be able to separate each link into the pass/fail system TestNG uses. In a for loop, it would do all of them and then if one fails, it would fail the method. I have over 1300 links to deal with, so taking it out of the for loop is suicide. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you have a known list of URLs for each page, and you want to validate the URL exists, and that it is not broken?  if so, you could make use of TestNG's `@dataprovider`.  `@dataprovider` is a "source", which feeds your `@Test`.  Each record in @dataprovider will be fed into `@Test`, one at a time, kind of like an iteration.  If you want to do it at a class level, then you can make use of @factory.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Greg I believe that will work for this implementation in particular, so thank you. However, I also have to automate a lot of things around the registration form and the rest of the site, so, for example, having a method that can identify the credential fields and fill them in and being able to reuse that method is pretty critical.

Comment: ok, so at this point, you need to design how you want to write your code. It is just java at this point.  Best thing to do is, write a list of test cases, and see what the common building blocks are, put them into its own method, class, etc., and reuse.

Comment: @Greg, so basically, just don't use TestNG for those cases is what you're saying?

Comment: TestNG is simply a framework that uses Java.  TestNG is mostly annotations (like JUnit) with a few of its own classes/APIs.  You write test cases in Java, and use TestNG as a framework for defining/executing/reporting.  A method with @Test, can call another method.  Every method does not need an annotation, per se.