# Certain tests not reporting in TestNG

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, annotations, testng

I'm using TestNG and Selenium in Eclipse, in Java. I have a method `test` that calls the other methods as support for the actions it needs to perform. I have them marked as part of the test using `@Test`.

```
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@Test
public static void checkValidity(String[] array, WebDriver driver){
    String partialURL = "";
    int brokenLinks = 0;
    for (int x=1; x<array.length; x+=2){
        partialURL = anonUserSitemapExperience.getPartialURL(driver, array[x]);
        if (partialURL.isEmpty()){
            System.err.println("The link \""+array[x]+"\" intended for the "+array[x-1]+" page is either broken or an external site.");
            brokenLinks++;
            brokenLinksTot++;
        }
        else{
            int found = anonUserSitemapExperience.findMatch(array, array.length, partialURL);
            if (found<1){
                System.err.println("A match was not found for "+array[x-1]+".\n"+array[x]+"\n"+partialURL);
                brokenLinks++;
                brokenLinksTot++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.err.println("\n"+brokenLinks+" broken link(s) was/were found.\n");
}

@Test
public static void openDropDowns(WebDriver driver){
    List<WebElement> dropdownArrows = driver.findElements(By.className("dropdownToggler"));
    Iterator<WebElement> itr = dropdownArrows.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        try{
            itr.next().click();
        }
        catch(ElementNotVisibleException e){
        }
    }
}

@Test
public static String[] createArray(List<WebElement> list){
    String[] linkArray = new String[list.size()*2];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int x=1; x<linkArray.length; x+=2){
        linkArray[x] = list.get(counter).getAttribute("href");
        try{
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C2%AE", "®");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%20", " ");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%27", "'");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%A4", "ä");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%B6", "ö");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%BC", "ü");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%84", "Ä");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%96", "Ö");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%C3%9C", "Ü");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%E2%80%93", "–");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%E2%84%A2", "™");
            linkArray[x] = linkArray[x].replaceAll("%25", "%");
            counter++;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
    int counter2 = 0;
    for (int x=0; x<linkArray.length; x+=2){
        linkArray[x] = list.get(counter2).getText();
        counter2++;
    }
    return linkArray;
}
    
@Test
public void test() {
    driver.get(siteUS);
    List<WebElement> topNavLinks = driver.findElement(By.className("topNavigationMenu")).findElements(By.className("menuLink"));
    int numLinks = topNavLinks.size();
    String[] topNavTitlesAndLinks = new String[numLinks*2];
    topNavTitlesAndLinks = createArray(topNavLinks);
    System.out.println("Filled titles and links array.");
    for (int x=1; x<topNavTitlesAndLinks.length; x+=2){
        driver.get(topNavTitlesAndLinks[x]);
        openDropDowns(driver);
        try{
            List<WebElement> menu = driver.findElement(By.className("asideNavigationMenu")).findElements(By.className("itemLink"));
            String[] menuArray = new String[menu.size()*2];
            menuArray = createArray(menu);
            checkValidity(menuArray, driver);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            if (topNavTitlesAndLinks[x-1].contains("Endodontics")){
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Endodontics"));
                Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                action.moveToElement(element).perform();
                WebElement subElement = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Access"));
                action.moveToElement(subElement);
                action.click();
                action.perform();
                openDropDowns(driver);
                List<WebElement> menu = driver.findElement(By.className("asideNavigationMenu")).findElements(By.className("itemLink"));
                String[] menuArray = new String[menu.size()*2];
                menuArray = createArray(menu);
                checkValidity(menuArray, driver);
            }
        }
    }
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
    
    System.err.println("\nTotal broken links found: "+brokenLinksTot);
    
    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double timeMin =((double)(time2-time1)/60000);
    int timeMinTrunc = (int)timeMin;
    double timeSec = (timeMin%1)*60;
        
    System.out.println("\n\nAll tests finished in "+timeMinTrunc+" minutes and "+timeSec+" seconds.");
}
```

Problem is, when I run it, I don't get pass fails from the methods that are called by `test`. My output is as follows:

> FAILED: test
>
> SKIPPED: checkValidity
>
> SKIPPED: openDropDowns

So how can I make all of the called methods report as well?

Comment: Seems like this has nothing to do with Selenium, or eclipse for that matter. How about narrowing the problem down a bit. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm using Selenium libraries and commands in my program, so I assumed I should include that. Eclipse is the IDE I'm using. Is that not how tags are intended to work? Sorry if I did it wrong.

Comment: Read the link! If you reduce the problem to the bare **minimum steps to reproduce**, you will find the only relevant things will be Java and TestNG. Everything else is just a distraction from what is really happening.

Comment: If you know for a fact that neither Selenium nor some hidden Eclipse preferences are affecting the way this code is running, then you know more than me and I would greatly appreciate that info since I'm trying to make this work. Do you know for sure that it is only TestNG and Java operating here to create this issue? And if so, do you know how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Non-void methods are ignored by TestNG
2. You should not call test methods yourself - it is a job for TestNG
3. Rewrite your test class so that methods annotated with `@Test` reflect your scenario and follow in a row. You can then use any helper methods you want.

E.g.

```
@BeforeClass
public void before() {
    //blah blah precondition goes here
}

@Test(priority=0)
public void start() {
    // testy test 0 goes here
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "start")
public void next() {
    Sysout(doSomething());
}

public String doSomething() {
    return "Helper method which I call in some test method";
}
```

**UPD**

If you want to invoke 400 times:

```
@DataProvider(name = "400_links")
public static String[][] getLinks() {
   // find your own way to create links here
   return new String[][] {{"http://foo"}, {"http://bar"}, ... , {"http://xyz"}};
}

@Test(dataProvider = "400_links")
public void checkAllLinks(String link) {
   checkValidityOrWhatever(link);
}

public void checkValidityOrWhatever(String link) {
   //blah blah http ftw
}
```

It will be launched 400 times, if you have 400 links provided in `getLinks()` Every iteration will be reported by Testng. Failed iterations will not stop other invocations from launch.

Comment: Is `Sysout` the command used to get TestNG to call the method?

Comment: No, it was instead of System.out.print().

Comment: Then how do I get TestNG to call the method if I shouldn't do it?

Comment: Testng will call the methods itself, if they're annotated with `@Test` or any `@Before\@After` annotations. If you're calling method yourself and expect it to be noted by TestNG - you're doing it wrong :)

Comment: Okay so can you think of any way to write this test so that the `checkValidity` method reports every time it is iterated without copying and pasting the methods over and over and over again? I have 400+ iterations of that method to go through and would like a report from it each time.

Comment: The first idea is to use TestNG dataProvider mechanism. If you have 400 links to check (they're are either stored somewhere or you generate them, I dunno), you just write one method, which will be invoked by TestNG 400 times, unless there are more arguments dataProvider can give. Thus you will have results of all iterations independently.

Answer (score 0):

Only the top level `@Test` will report results. checkValidity, IMO, would not be a test case, it is more of a verification and would cause a test to pass or fail.  Remember, `@Test` should denote a test case, a scenario, from start to finish.  I should be able to look at a `@Test` and know exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  In your example, it looks like you are trying to validate the entries in the listbox.  Your test name should reflect that, and the way it is written, the first failure hit, the test will fail.  If you need to validate each and every entry first before failing, then you will need to build your failure message appropriately, and not throw an exception until after all the iterations/clicks have completed.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for how to format this so that each checkValidity method reports pass or fail? I'm trying to avoid failing the whole test case, but having a report from each checkValidity is exactly what I'm going for. I am validating those entries, exactly. How would I do it so that I don't fail the test case, but rather that iteration of checkValidity?

Comment: i don't get it, does System.err.println() cause the loop to exit?  If so, get rid of it, you have other means to log results, I suggest using apache's logger instead.  Or just write to console.   Then, check if brokenLinks is > 0, if so, fail the test then.  Most folks use Assert.fail(), or some other Assert method to trigger a failure.

Comment: No, it doesn't cause the loop to exit. It's a just a write to console action. That isn't the functionality I want. I want `checkValidity` to run multiple times, and each time it runs, to pass or fail and have output that reflects that in the TestNG console. That's the part I can't get.